# Android tint on off with java

Tags: android, android-activity, tint

I made a custom `imagebutton`.

It is possible to set image `src` and selected tint color.

I want to toggle original image and set tint color `image` when button clicked.

I tried this.(this is not full source, just wrote point)

CustomImageButton.java

```
public class CustomImageButton extends LinearLayout {

  View view;
  ImageView imageView;
  private Drawable defaultDrawable;
  private Drawable tintDrawable;

  public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
    super(context, attr);

    args = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attr, R.styleable.CustomImageButton);
    init(context);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
  view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_image_button, this);
  imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imvCustomButtonImg);

  getArgs();
  getDefaultValues();

  setSelect(isSelected);
}

private void getDefaultValues()
{
  defaultDrawable = getContext().getDrawable(imageSrc);
  tintDrawable = getContext().getDrawable(imageSrc);
  DrawableCompat.setTintList(tintDrawable, getContext().getColorStateList(selectedTintColorId));
}

  public void setTintColor()
  {
    if(isSelected == false) {
      imageView.setImageDrawable(defaultDrawable);
    }
    else
    {
      imageView.setImageDrawable(tintDrawable);
    }
  }
```

This is work well when first time.

But after recreate, activity, default image is set tint color.

So `buttons` set tint color if I click or not.

I guess `DrawableCompat.setTintList(tintDrawable, getContext().getColorStateList(selectedTintColorId));` is override application's src.

Have you any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the state of your view you can do this my overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` of your custom view. I create a sample here https://gist.github.com/giaquino/092e37f9522e9436b912d2488c237a31

Also you can create a `ColorStateList` resource and set it as your `android:tint/app:tint` for your button instead of creating another drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FF0000" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```